# How to handle timeouts in Cassandra + AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-driver

I've a Lambda function with VPC that connecting to Cassandra.

I think that because of cold-start or other issue it can't connect to the Cassandra at all, the Lambda have timeout of 10s, I want to add timeout for the Cassandra as well, if the first connection not being made I will kill the script and return that there was an issue.

I'm using cassandra-driver for node js:
https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver/

Conneciton:

```
const cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
const client = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints: ['127.0.0.1'], keyspace: 'keyspace' });
```

I can't use the timeout of the nodejs and then check the connection because the Lambda won't finish the code until the timeout will finished, even if everything was okay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have timeout available to you as an optional parameter for the `Client` object [here](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver/blob/master/lib/client.js)

It should be a matter of assigning this optional parameter to a value of your preference. You should also look for handling the connection problem in the callback function.

```
const cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
/* Documentation: github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver/blob/master/lib/client.js - line 120*/
const client = new cassandra.Client(
{ 
   contactPoints: ['127.0.0.1'],
   keyspace: 'keyspace',
   socketOptions:
   {
      connectTimeout: 2000
   }
});
```

After creating the client you should be able to specify (in case it doesn't work) a callback on the connect method.

```
/* Documentation: github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver/blob/master/lib/client.js - line 320 */
client.connect(function (err) {
   if (err) return console.error(err); /* your attempt to connect is terminated here. */
   console.log('Connected to cluster with %d host(s): %j', 
   client.hosts.length, client.hosts.keys());
});
```

Once you've verified your (err) is present - your connection attempt is basically terminated. It's up to you to re-try / kill / do something else with your AWS lambda.